# Jquery error on load couldn't find the error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, exception, uncaught-exception

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(setInterval(function(){
        $("#appointment").html(
            " <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=""><i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i><span class="badge"><?php echo htmlentities($noti_count); ?></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </a>"
        );
    }), 1000);
</script>
```

I get error " Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list " in console 
i couldn't understand why !please help me.

Comment: You can't use double quotes in a double quoted string. Use single quotes for the class names and it should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many mistakes

1. `$(document).ready()` expects function as an argument.
2. `setIterval` started and closed. but `$(document).ready` method is not closed.
3. String formation for HTML is wrong. enclose `'` single quote inside double or vice versa.

Try this. and instead of `10` use your PHP code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $("#appointment").html('<a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i><span class="badge">10</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="appointment"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! i'm new to jquery!